# Best Practices for storing simple related data in mySQL

Tags: mysql, database-schema

Say I'm storing a number of values taken from certain sensors, and I also want to store if the sensor connected to a certain column is active or not. Each computer will have exactly 4 sensors. Would it make more sense to store a Computer entry (which holds some other data too) and then the sensor readings and activity boolenas in a single table like this:

Computer Columns:

```
foo
bar
sensor1
sensor1_active
sensor2
sensor2_active
sensor3
sensor3_active
```

or to split it into two tables with a foreign key, like this:

Computer Columns:

```
id
foo
bar
```

Sensor Columns:

```
id
id_Computer
sensor_reading
sensor_active
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer to this is a little bit fuzzy because we don't know how or where you're using your data. Typically I'd say go with the just adding columns for each sensor to the computer table; it keeps it simple and unless you expect to add more sensors having the columns directly on the table, it should suit your purposes well.

Comment: If it helps, the output will be a basic php page that edits the database. (The database is also queried by an iPhone app that connects to each of the sensors). The modules we use are hard-wired with four sensors for each module, so there won't be adding any new sensors per module, only new modules.

Comment: @KevinWhiteside Yeah if it's just a simple edit page and the sensors are static you should be fine with the values as columns.